# IntelliJ IDEA jshell_console still reports error after rebuilding the project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, jshell

I'm new to Java. I wrote some simple code that converts integer to binary. I want to test if the code works in the jshell_console so that i won't need a "main" every time.

At first, I forgot to use "public" when I declared the class in my source code, as well as its methods (for the conversion). So the jshell console reported error. But after I corrected the error and rebuilt the project, the console still failed. The weird thing is after I close and restart IntelliJ, the console finally works as expected...

Is it caused byIntelliJ's fault or me? And I wonder how I should recompile or rebuild the source code / project to make the console respond immediately without the need to restart IntelliJ.

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While JShell console is opened IDEA doesn't recompile your code. So old code version was used until you restarted IDE. Next time you could just close console and run "Rebuild".